# Google Maps API: Change Polygon Colors (Polygons Created From NetworkLink KML)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

### Background

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API to create a map for a website. I want to be able to edit it with a GUI, and have changes automatically update the public map.

I can accomplish this via Google's MyMaps. I've created a map using it, and then exported a NetworkLink KML file. I read that KML file into my JS API map as a KML layer.

### Problem

I'm not sure how to interact with the data once it is in the JS API map. I need to style polygons as different colors, and use functions such as `containsLocation()`.

### Current Code

**KML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>Lighting</name>
        <description><![CDATA[A map showing all lighting reps.]]></description>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>Lighting</name>
            <Link>
                <href>http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&amp;mid=zUHNjsLRU3p0.k_6G1fwoLGr4</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

**JS API Code**

```
var gMap = new google.maps.Map(element, opts);
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'data.kml',
  map: gMap
});
```

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AFNMZ1mRg746bZaKR3GR?p=preview) (Plunker)

### Question

Can I edit these polygons, changing colors, etc? How would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically change colour of KML polygon in Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992241/dynamically-change-colour-of-kml-polygon-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way (currently) to modify the colors of objects defined in a KmlLayer is to change the KML.

Other options:

- use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) that render the KML using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects.  Note that these third party parsers are subject to the same domain restriction for XmlHttpRequest, so the KML must be on the same domain as the web page or served through a proxy.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/FDI_Lighting_Reps.kml)

- import the KML into a FusionTablesLayer, which can be styled dynamically.

Comment: Actually, I've been looking at this more and I think there's a difference. When the KML feed is coming straight from Google My Maps, it contains `<Folder>` elements, which geoxml can't parse.