# Interactive change of KML Polygons Style in Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, kml

I have a database with KML Plolygons representing german postal regions.

I initialize the map like this to get the polygons displayed.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var plzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://xxxxx.de/index.php?option=com_map&task=kml.getplz&search=542',
    map: map
});
```

Everything works like a charm. I can even style the Polygons by defining styles in the kml file.

[image]

My question is; how can I change the style of polygon objects interactively on the map now. I want a mouse hover effect for example or set polygons as marked on mouseclick.

As far as I discovered I can add a click event.

```
plzLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
    console.log(this.objInfo);
});
```

The event object contains a list called featureData with the infoWindowHtml and also a ID of the object.
Something like **id:"g37a571f194fd2a75"**

How can I access the polygon to change style dynamically without reload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highlight a polygon while on click using kml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478441/highlight-a-polygon-while-on-click-using-kml)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the data displayed by [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) (at least at the present time).  If you want to change the styling of KML after it is displayed, some options are:

1. import it into [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) (allows dynamic styling, but doesn't seem compatible with your current strategy)
2. use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3/) which display the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, which can be styled

[example using geoxml3 which changes polygon styles on mouseover](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_polygon_highlight.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution outside the google world.

I am using the open source **Lefleat** Javascript library 
Lefleat is really fast and easy to use and it renders geodata as SVG layer on OpenStreetMap oder Google maps.
http://leafletjs.com/

I decided to use GeoJSON because it is shorter and faster.

The final tool.
http://www.unternehmen-selbstaendigkeit.de/148-der-online-gebietsmanager.html
(german)